# How to hide a window from Super + W overview mode?

Tags: unity, launcher, window, system-tray

I have an application that shows me a useful unread item count in its Unity launcher icon as long as the application is open and running.

However, I do not need to have its window shown in Super + W overview mode.

Is it possible to keep a running (open) application in the launcher without having its window shown in overview mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply minimize the window. Example from my 16.04  desktop:

[image]
*Image 1: Terminal window not minimized - shows up in the window spread*

[image]
*Image 2: Terminal window minimized - doesn't show up in the window spread*